# Stuck in an endless loop

Tags: java

I set a loop condition to be a<b. However it still continues when a>b .I get the loop in **input==3**
I haven't finished the code, so if you want to run it[input==3] you have to initialize the game size and after that the game .
I tried both while and for loops and im getting the same results.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Assignment2 {
 static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Random rand = new Random();
  int input;
  int[][] board = null;
  int rows = 0;
  int columns = 0;

  do {

   System.out.println("0. End Program" + "\n" + "1. Initialize Game Size" + "\n" + "2. Initialize Game" + "\n"
     + "3. Print 1 stage Ahead" + "\n" + "4. Print k stage ahead");
   input = sc.nextInt();

   if (input < 0 || input > 4) {
    System.out.println("Wrong menu input");
   }
   if (input == 0) {

    System.out.println("End Program");
    break;
   }
   if (input == 1) { // Setting a game board size
    System.out.println("Enter number of rows");
    rows = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of columns");
    columns = sc.nextInt();
    if (rows < 1 || columns < 1) {
     System.out.println("Wrong game size");

    } else {
     board = new int[rows][columns];

     System.out.println("set Game size");

    }
   }
   if (input == 2) { // initialize a random game with 1 and 0
    if (columns == 0 || rows == 0) {
     System.out.println("No game size stored");

    } else {
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
       if (rand.nextBoolean())
        board[i][j] = 1;
       else
        board[i][j] = 0;

      }
     }

     for (int k = 0; k < board.length; k++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < board[k].length; j++) { // loop to check every square in the board
       System.out.print(board[k][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
     }
    }
   }
   if (input == 3) { // 1 movement ahead in the game
    for (int k = 0; k < board.length; k++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < board[k].length; j++) { // loop to check every square in the board
      if (board[k][j] == 1) {
       int rowMove = 0; // checks for possible movement
       int columnMove = 0; // checks for possible movement
       int counter = 0;
       for (rowMove = 0; rowMove < rows || columnMove < columns; rowMove++) {
        for (columnMove = 0; rowMove < rows || columnMove < columns; columnMove++) {
         int difrow = rowMove - rows; // row distance
         int difcolumn = columnMove - columns; // column distance
         if (difrow < 0) { // absolute number
          difrow = -difrow;

         }
         if (difcolumn < 0) { // absolute number
          difcolumn = -difcolumn;
         }
         if (difcolumn + difrow == 3) {
          counter++;

         }

        }

       }
       if (counter == 1 || counter == 2) {
        board[k][j] = 1;
       } else {
        board[k][j] = 0;
       }
      }
     }

    }
    for (int k = 0; k < board.length; k++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < board[k].length; j++) { // loop to check every square in the board
      System.out.print(board[k][j] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
    }
   }
  } while (input != 0);
 }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to at least point out to us exactly where the problem is.  Few people will have the time/patience to read through your entire code looking for problems.

Comment: As I stated, the problem is in input==3. I'm getting an endless loop and i have no idea why. 
It happens in :"
for (rowMove = 0; rowMove < rows || columnMove < columns; rowMove++) {
        for (columnMove = 0; rowMove < rows || columnMove < columns; columnMove++) {"
if you want to CTRL+F it.

Comment: Consider using `if() {} else if () {}` statements instead of multiple `if` statements, or even `switch(input) { case 'value': /* blah blah */ }`.

Comment: Also don't use tabs. This may break if others edit your code and also makes your question hard to read.

Comment: Don't hide details in comments that should be in the question via an [edit]. Also: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

in your inner for loop

```
for (columnMove = 0; rowMove < rows || columnMove < columns; columnMove++)
```

the condition is to iterate as long as `rowMove < rows || columnMove < columns` but only `columnMove` get advanced, so  `rowMove < rows` is always true

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this :

```
for (rowMove = 0; rowMove < rows; rowMove++) {
    for (columnMove = 0; columnMove < columns; columnMove++)
```